# Java catching exceptions inside a class called from a swingworker

Tags: java, exception, swingworker

well, I have this code:

```
SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
   @Override
   public Void doInBackground() {
       Connection checker = new Connection();
       do{
           checker.checkConnection();
       }while(true);
   }}
```

Here is the method

> checkConnection()

```
public void checkConnection(){
do{
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("You're connected");
        }
        online = true;
    }catch(Exception noConnessione){
        System.out.println("No connection..."); 
        System.out.println("I'm going to try again in 30s...");
        robot.delay(30000);
        online = false;
    }
}while(online == false);}
```

well, if there is no connection it doesn't go inside the catch block, but if I use the same code without the swingworker, it goes in.

I absolutely need the swingworker so how can I solve this?

Comment: Swing worker works as expected. I guess you need to post full code. Maybe there is a bug somewhere else.

Comment: @mko: Never the ***full*** code, but always if possible a decent [mcve].

Comment: WOW, a Robot just to avoid the InterruptedException? but seriously, not sure if connecting as often as possible to Google is such a good idea, at least insert some delay after a successful connection too

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the bot does lot more than this, I just try to post minimal code and yes, in the entire version there is a delay too.

Comment: the robot part was not meant to be serious,; long time ago I just spent some time considering to use it to ignore the InterruptedException... Anyway, is the problem also happening with this minimal code? It's working for me.

Comment: Well for this code there is no problem, I didn't try it srry, but the entire code is too long to paste it inside the comment. btw I can't figure out why it works without the swingworker but if it is inside a swingworker it doesn't.
I have a selenium bot, if I click on links inside chrome while the bot is doing its own stuff, it just stops doing it. If I use the exactly same code but without the swingworker it goes on doing its own stuff. I do not know if I explained it well

Comment: Maybe there is an Error being thrown that is not being caught. I assume you are not calling the `get` method of SwingWorker (since it is not assumed to terminate) so any uncaught Exception/Error wil not be forwarded. Use a try-catch(Throwable) around the WHOLE `doInBackground`  **or**  override the `done` method just to call `get` and catch any Exceptions.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger no, I'm not calling the get method, I'm going to try, thank you, if it will solve my problem i'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working just fine

```
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Simple {

  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    System.out.println("Starting worker");
    SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
      @Override
      public Void doInBackground() {
        Connection checker = new Connection();
        do{
          System.out.println("Running routine test");
          checker.checkConnection();
        }while(true);
      }
    };
    worker.execute();
    while(true);
  }
}

class Connection {
  boolean online = false;
  public void checkConnection() {
    System.out.println("Check connection loop");
    while(online == false) {
      try{
        URL url = new URL("http://yyy.google.com");
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("You're connected");
        }
        online = true;
      }catch(Exception noConnessione){
        online = false;
      }
      if(online == false) {
        try {
          System.out.println("No connection...");
          System.out.println("I'm going to try again in 3s...");
          System.out.flush();
          Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
          System.out.println("I was awaken");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

execution follows

```
> javac Simple.java
> java Simple
Starting worker
Running routine test
Check connection loop
No connection...
I'm going to try again in 3s...
No connection...
I'm going to try again in 3s...
No connection...
I'm going to try again in 3s...
No connection...
I'm going to try again in 3s...
No connection...
I'm going to try again in 3s...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an uncaught Exception/Error aborting the `doInBackground` method. This Exception will be silently caught by the Swingworker and only be reported when the `get` method is called.

The `get` method will block until the SwingWorker is terminated, which is not intended in above code (forever loop). So the call should be mode inside the overridden `done`method:

```
SwingWorker<Void,Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        ...
    }
    @Override
    public void done() {
        try {
            get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // TODO
        }
    }
};
```

but be aware that `done` is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread!

Alternative, have the **whole** content of `doInBackground` inside a try-catch:

```
    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

*not a solution but should help find the error, and therefore hopefully the solution*

Comment: Great, thank you man! solved it using get();
I had an unhandled nullpointerexception and using get() method I had the stack trace to find out the problem.
Again thank you!